# How to fetch data from a collection named group in mongodb using PHP code

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal-7

This is my PHP code for fetching data from a collection in mongodb:

```
$m = new Mongo('localhost');
$m->connect();
$db = $m->mydb;
$collection = $db->fields_current;
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo $obj["title"] . "\n";
}
```

The code works fine for the collection `fields_current`. But, I have a collection like this `fields_current.node` where `node` is the named group of the collection. How do I fetch data from the named group.

**Edit:**

After following PeterM's answer I am getting an empty MongoCursor object. This is my new code:

```
$m = new Mongo('localhost');
$m->connect();
$db = $m->mydb;
$collection = $db->fields_current;
$query = array(array('group_name' => 'node', 'type' => 'content-type'), array('title' => 1)); // SELECT title FROM fields_current WHERE group_name = 'node' AND type = 'content-type'
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo $obj["title"] . "\n";
}
```

*Some more details*: I am using Drupal and `node` refers to the 'node' table, `type` is the 'node-type'. The collection name is `fields_current.node` and the record structure is this:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoInt32(37),
  '_type' => 'node',
  '_bundle' => 'content-type',
  '_revision_id' => new MongoInt32(37),
  'nid' => new MongoInt32(37),
  'vid' => new MongoInt32(37),
  'type' => 'content-type',
  'language' => 'und',
  'title' => 'title',
  'uid' => new MongoInt32(1),
  'status' => new MongoInt32(1),
  'created' => new MongoInt32(1342065549),
  'changed' => new MongoInt32(1342065549),
  'comment' => new MongoInt32(1),
  'promote' => new MongoInt32(0),
  'sticky' => new MongoInt32(0),
  'tnid' => new MongoInt32(0),
  'translate' => new MongoInt32(0),
  'field_cutom_field' => 
  array (
    'value' => 'foobar',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its Drupal you do not have to specify the database name, just like when you write queries for MySql. And also there is a different function for getting a collection object.

```
// Suppose you have a collection called 'collection_name', then you can get its object using this code.
$collection = mongodb_collection('collection_name');

// Suppose you have a collection called 'collection_name.group', where 'group' is the named group of this collection, then you can get its object using this code.
$collection = mongodb_collection('collection_name', 'group');

// Rest of the operations will be same.
$cursor = $collection->find(array('type' => 'content-type'));
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
  ....
  // Do your work...
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('node' => 'group_name'));
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php for more examples

Comment: But it returns an empty MongoCursor object. How to fetch the fields from there. I referred the documentation, looks like I am missing something. I am new to mongodb.

Comment: Query is first parameter to find, while fields is second. You made one array. It should be `$collection->find($query, $fields);` so it should be `$query = array('group_name' => 'node', 'type' => 'content-type');` (NOTE: you don't have field group_name, should it be _type?) and `$fields = array('title')`